# Time elapsed since a property was last accessed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, livecharts

I have a property which gets and sets a list of integers, which I use to draw a chart using LiveCharts.

The values are being passed from an external hardware device. Sometimes the values may be unavailable due to a hardware problem, during which no values are being passed to my app, and so the property is not being fired. I still want to plot the values, but as `NaN`.

How can I detect if a property has not been accessed/set in my code, say for 10 milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the thing I was searching for is a  [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) . The ElapsedEventHandler serves the purpose I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign DateTime.Now to another instance variable in the setter of your property. And then in the getter you can return NaN if that value is more than 10ms old. Something like below.

```
        DateTime _lastUpdate;
        double _value;
        TimeSpan _maxInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
        public double Value
        {
            get
            {
                return (DateTime.Now - _lastUpdate) <=  _maxInterval ? _value : double.NaN;
            }
            set
            {
                _lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                _value = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: But the question remains as to how to fire up the property when no one is accessing it from outside?